# Node.js - window bits argument in zlib does not support >15 bits?

Tags: python, node.js, zlib

I have a program that I am rewriting into Node.js. It is a Python program that base64 decodes it and decompresses it.

This is the original Python code:

```py
import base64
import zlib


def decode_str(data: str) -> str:
    base64_decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode())
    decompressed = zlib.decompress(base64_decoded, 15 | 32)
    return decompressed.decode()
```

I'd like to use it on the string below:

`H4sIAAAAAAAAC5VV25HDIAxsSM4gCfGY-7oaUgAFXAtX_EngC5DYJsmMUeLVrh4I8nPnBFhcIX1YH8RCIgWpGa7Glw1LKOicK7FgQbElqXsq-PsBHU_p6Kg074VEPpQwn0Z4S4SK8c9zye_JyKnMh_mEhdC6uXTIjhVgZetymcMhHQO-FZwP2PDzjQzOjDQTmvGga_se25vdJDN3zvUXAeraBCrw7evaUHTNILgvBFJLEDMwYIggEeyFwBYgwJadOqgaeVAPgnRLUUnZGQmzKCtoihzUR7BSLSBZJI2T9QNs8ZIoQfS4PEI2dpQa8oYGYAz-CaGGjBTtHYjF02wPeAMcZvJQY77ZO3utlW08lLY7J3P2jv-j7C35b8ZEQfbBlJKFFxnaAbGKaS-GLoSk_YNgLYqu7sEk4EMXiCaQDgS2S4XcFcQUwqcKQl2BTcGvi2gzsWfAnZ9tJDaUPhWDzqPhtmsvW1vb3V1oHpgnNF2iconSOng9IZsW_FA4H4iJkvN0qK4IaZkGY6-DB3Q_ASPsp7PRkEE7jWfjBY0nkdkvXd7I37_kP6J4iW7X8NkW77mldYV46GL_M-pTB3sa71qNu4me23bdxdoBuwXzcMF64pcbNl8NQ4v0fCUfXca7f5DpenPTjPJZlHouOHKvdzWlXupYe-7bcEb5AxMHn1whCQAA`

When I run it in Python, it works fine. But when I rewrote it in JavaScript, it errored.
This is the code:

```js
const zlib = require('zlib')
let b64decrypt = (encodedData) => {
    return Buffer.from(encodedData, 'base64').toString();
}
let decrypt = (ls) => {
    let fin = b64decrypt(ls);
    return zlib.gunzipSync(fin, { windowBits: 15 | 32 });
}
let l = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAC5VV25HDIAxsSM4gCfGY-7oaUgAFXAtX_EngC5DYJsmMUeLVrh4I8nPnBFhcIX1YH8RCIgWpGa7Glw1LKOicK7FgQbElqXsq-PsBHU_p6Kg074VEPpQwn0Z4S4SK8c9zye_JyKnMh_mEhdC6uXTIjhVgZetymcMhHQO-FZwP2PDzjQzOjDQTmvGga_se25vdJDN3zvUXAeraBCrw7evaUHTNILgvBFJLEDMwYIggEeyFwBYgwJadOqgaeVAPgnRLUUnZGQmzKCtoihzUR7BSLSBZJI2T9QNs8ZIoQfS4PEI2dpQa8oYGYAz-CaGGjBTtHYjF02wPeAMcZvJQY77ZO3utlW08lLY7J3P2jv-j7C35b8ZEQfbBlJKFFxnaAbGKaS-GLoSk_YNgLYqu7sEk4EMXiCaQDgS2S4XcFcQUwqcKQl2BTcGvi2gzsWfAnZ9tJDaUPhWDzqPhtmsvW1vb3V1oHpgnNF2iconSOng9IZsW_FA4H4iJkvN0qK4IaZkGY6-DB3Q_ASPsp7PRkEE7jWfjBY0nkdkvXd7I37_kP6J4iW7X8NkW77mldYV46GL_M-pTB3sa71qNu4me23bdxdoBuwXzcMF64pcbNl8NQ4v0fCUfXca7f5DpenPTjPJZlHouOHKvdzWlXupYe-7bcEb5AxMHn1whCQAA';
console.log(decrypt(l))
```

I tried running it, and it gave me this error:

```
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "options.windowBits" is out of range. It must be >= 8 and <= 15. Received 47
```

And when I removed the `windowBits` option, it gave me this error:

```
Error: incorrect header check
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

`gunzipSync` is already expecting gzip input. It does not need the `| 32`. Just leave off the options.

However, the data you have provided as an example is corrupted. It starts off as a valid gzip stream, but it contains invalid deflate data.